# Copy Python method reference without hash symbol

Tags: python, pycharm

[image]

Currently when you "Copy Reference" of a Python method in PyCharm it uses a hash symbol between the class and the method. Like this:

```
project.apps.tests.test_api.TestFoo#test_bar
```

Is there a way to configure PyCharm to use a dot instead of a hash. Like this:

```
project.apps.tests.test_api.TestFoo.test_bar
```

Comment: This is a fine question, but it's more suited for Stack Overflow. I've voted to migrate it there.

Comment: Ok please migrate.

Answer (score 0):

It appears this has been fixed in PyCharm 2019.2